# "at the picnic" vs "on a picnic"

Tags: prepositions

My question is can I say:

> I was **at** a picnic yesterday?

Or do I have to use **on**?

I was confused because it sounded correct at first, but then I got no results when I looked it up on Google.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the verb being used. We can say:

> I went **on** a picnic yesterday.
>   I went **to** a picnic yesterday.

but not:

> I went **at** a picnic yesterday.

However, we *can* say:

> I **was** at a picnic yesterday.
>   We **were** on a picnic yesterday. (Note: this one sounds a little unusual with 'I' instead of 'we'.)

but not:

> I was **to** a picnic yesterday.